# How to change the background image through the tag "selected"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the background image of the body (id = "shelf") using a drop-down menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTheme()
{document.getElementById("shelf").style.backgroundImage = "url("+theme+")";
  var e = document.getElementById("themes");
  var theme = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
}  
</script>
</head>
<body id="shelf">
<select id="themes" onChange="changeTheme()">
  <option value="images/bg/default.png">Default</option>
  <option value="images/bg/oriental.png">Oriental</option>
  <option value="images/bg/office.png">Office</option>
  <option value="images/bg/old.png">Old</option>
</select>
</body>
```

But I don't know why it doesn't work.. Where's the problem in code?

Comment: You should probably set the `theme` variable **before** you try to use it? And the body would be `document.body`!

Comment: Err, you are using the `theme` variable before you define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working.

```
function changeTheme() {
    var e = document.getElementById("themes");
    var theme = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("shelf").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + theme + ")";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the behavior you are seeing?

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTheme()
{

  var e = document.getElementById("themes");
  var theme = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(theme);
  document.getElementById("shelf").style.backgroundImage = "url("+theme+")";
}  
</script>
</head>
<body id="shelf">
<select id="themes" onChange="changeTheme()">
  <option value="images/bg/default.png">Default</option>
  <option value="images/bg/oriental.png">Oriental</option>
  <option value="images/bg/office.png">Office</option>
  <option value="images/bg/old.png">Old</option>
</select>
</body>    
</html>
```